# django post_save signal is getting triggered twice when I try to save the instance, it is actually triggering the update part

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have two models Invoce and Payin. Invoice can be payed in multiple payins. While updating Invoice details with post_save signal. after create logic is executed I attach an Invoice Id to the Payin instance and save it. This save is triggering the signal again(as it's supposed to be) this time update logic i.e in the else part of if create: is executed there by one payin is added twice to the paid amount in invoice. How can I avoid the Update logic when I save instance in the signal logic.

```
class Invoice(BaseEntity):
    """ Invoices are generated based on events state"""

    STATUS_CHOICES=(
        ('CREATED', 'Created'),
        ('CONFIRMED', 'Confirmed'),
        ('PARTIAL_PAYMENT', 'Partially Paid'),
        ('RECEIVED', 'Received'),
        ('CLOSED', 'Closed')
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
            Customer,
            related_name='invoices',
        )
    event = models.ForeignKey(
            'booking.Event',
            related_name='invoice',
        )
    generated_date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name='date invoice generated'
        )
    due_date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name='date payment is expected'

        )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length =15,
        choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
        default = 'CREATED',
    )
    amount = models.IntegerField(
            default=500,
            validators=[
                MinValueValidator(
                    10,
                    message = 'Amount should be greater than 10'
                ),

                MaxValueValidator(
                    10000000,
                    message = 'Amount should be less than 10000000'
                ),
            ]
        )
    paid = models.IntegerField(
            default=500,
            validators=[
                MinValueValidator(
                    10,
                    message = 'Amount should be greater than 10'
                ),

                MaxValueValidator(
                    10000000,
                    message = 'Amount should be less than 10000000'
                ),
            ]
        )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Invoice_Detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Invoice_Update', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Invoice_Delete', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

class Payin(BaseEntity):
    """ Payins from all customers"""
    MODE_CHOICES=(
        ('BANK', 'Bank'),
        ('CHEQUE', 'Cheque'),
        ('DD', 'Demand Draft'),
        ('CASH', 'Cash'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
            'customers.Customer',
            related_name='customer_payins',
            blank = True,
            null = True,
        )
    event = models.ForeignKey(
            'booking.Event',
            related_name='event_payins',
            blank = True,
            null =True,
        )
    date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name='payment date'
        )
    time = models.TimeField(
            verbose_name='payment time'

        )
    amount = models.IntegerField(
            default=500,
            validators=[
                MinValueValidator(
                    10,
                    message = 'Amount should be greater than 10'
                ),

                MaxValueValidator(
                    10000000,
                    message = 'Amount should be less than 10000000'
                ),
            ]
        )
    mode = models.CharField(
        max_length =15,
        choices = MODE_CHOICES,
        default = 'CASH',
    )
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
            Invoice,
            related_name='payins',
            blank = True,
            null = True,
        )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Payin_Detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Payin_Update', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('accounting:Payin_Delete', kwargs={'id': self.id})    


@receiver(post_save, sender = Payin)
    def update_event_invoice_based_on_payin(sender,instance, created, **kwargs):
        payin = instance
        #print(dir(instance))
    if created:
        try:
            event = Event.objects.get(pk = payin.event.id )
            if event.status != 'COMPLETED':
                print('advance before save in post_save in create is: ', event.advance)
                event.advance = event.advance + payin.amount
                event.save()
                print('advance after save in post_save in create is: ' , event.advance)
            else:
                invoice = Invoice.objects.get(event = event.id)
                if invoice.paid + payin.amount <= invoice.amount:
                    print('post_save before save :',invoice.paid )
                    invoice.paid = (invoice.paid + payin.amount)
                    print(invoice.paid)
                    if invoice.paid == invoice.amount:
                        invoice.status = 'PAID'
                        invoice.save()
                        print('post_save after save in paid :',invoice.paid)
                        payin.invoice = invoice
                        print('paid')
                        payin.save()
                    else:
                        invoice.status = 'PARTIAL_PAYMENT'
                        invoice.save()
                        print('post_save after save in partial payment :',invoice.paid)
                        payin.invoice = invoice
                        print('partial payment')
                        payin.save()
        finally:
            #del instance._del
            pass
    else:
        event = Event.objects.get(pk = payin.event.id )
        if event.status != 'COMPLETED':
            print('advance before save in post_save in modify is: ' ,event.advance)
            event.advance = event.advance + payin.amount
            event.save()
            print('advance after save in post_save in modify is: ' , event.advance)
        else:
            invoice = Invoice.objects.get(event = event.id)
            if invoice.paid + payin.amount <= invoice.amount:
                #print(invoice.paid + payin.amount)
                print('post_save before save in update :',invoice.paid)
                invoice.paid = (invoice.paid + payin.amount)
                print(invoice.paid)
                if invoice.paid == invoice.amount:
                    invoice.status = 'PAID'
                    invoice.save()
                    print('post_save after save in paid in update :',invoice.paid)
                    print('paid')
                else:
                    invoice.status = 'PARTIAL_PAYMENT'
                    invoice.save()
                    print('post_save after save in partial payment in update :',invoice.paid)
                    print('partial payment')
```

Comment: You called the save() method again in the signals also, please remove the save method calling within in the signal and try..

Comment: but that save is necessary as I have updated it with invoice id. with out that it will be lost.